# Change in vibrionic energy in at atom at a higher excited electron state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, spectroscopy, vibrations

I was studying the coupling of Vibrational and Electronic energies and was left confused at one aspect of the subject.

Consider the image showing a transition from one electronic state to a higher excited state:

[image]

With vibrionic coupling, my question was about the transition from $\nu_0$ to $\nu_{1}'$.

**Does the transition cause a change in vibronic energy as well as electronic energy of the molecule?**

And also, by my interpretation, is it correct to say that the transition from $\nu_0$ to $\nu_{0}'$ signify only the energy needed to change the molecule from the electronic ground state to the electronic excited state i.e. the vibrational energy of the molecule is the same?

Answer (score 0):

Every transition will result in *some* change in the vibrational energy.  Even a transition like the one shown on the left (with no vibrational coupling) will result in some change, because the effective potential for the vibrational motion depends on the electronic state.  (This is *not* evident in the figure, unfortunately.)  So even a transition from the lowest vibrational substate of one electronic state to the lowest vibrational substate of a different electronic state ($\nu_{0}\rightarrow \nu_{0}'$) will change the zero-point energy of the vibrational mode.

However, there are certainly situations where the sharpness of the effective potential does not change all that much between different electronic states.  In that case, your description is approximately accurate.  The transition $\nu_{0}\rightarrow\nu_{1}'$ represents a change in the electronic quantum state *and* a change (by 1) in the number of quanta present in the vibrational mode.

Answer (score 0):

As posed, your question is a little bit problematic. The reality is that a vibronic transition is a combination of electronic and vibrational state changes together. It is possible to separate these degrees of freedom (at least approximately), which would allow you to “slice up” the contributions to the energy into electronic and vibrational parts. The Born-Oppenheimer approximation is the vehicle for formally doing this. Unfortunately, there are situations where the electronic and vibrational motions are significantly coupled and you cannot properly separate the motions at all. Dealing with this is extremely complicated in practice, and leads to a class of “non Born-Oppenheimer” problems. Luckily for us, it is often very approximately correct, so we will just assume that this works unless we have reason to believe otherwise.

But to your final point, no the transition is not just the electronic state energy difference! In general, the vibrational states are directly tied to the electronic state that they are associated with. In other words, the vibrational energy of the $n=0$ vibrational state in the ground electronic state will NOT match the vibrational energy of the $n^\prime=0$ vibrational state in the excited electronic state. Only if you get very lucky will the natural frequency (omitting anharmonicity) of two electronic states be the same.